# Typecasting Unsigned Long Long to Character Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have legacy code which contains the following code logic:

```
unsigned long long address; /* Its content = Some Address, not a normal value */

strcmp (address, (const char*)some_char_buffer);
```

This gives a warning with gcc.

Can somebody suggest some way of typecasting the variable 'address' into a char pointer so that it can be decoded properly and gcc gives no warning?

Comment: I'd like to note that you should be using `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` from `stdint.h` to store pointer values as integers. Otherwise you risk losing precision (or, alternatively, gaining precision, which will be lost when you convert back and can cause similar problems).

Comment: If there weren't any problems, Chris, it wouldn't be legacy code...  As part of a modernization effort, your recommendation is sensible.  I note that the `const char *` cast in the question is probably not needed, unless `some_char_buffer` is actually `unsigned char` (or, less likely, `signed char`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I have a terrible tendency to skip to the code part, and I totally missed the words "legacy code" in the first line. I feel a bit silly now...

Comment: @ChrisLutz: If it is any consolation, you're not alone in running into that problem...(me too, in other words).

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming the content of `address` is really just a pointer**: You can probably do:

```
strcmp ((char*)address, (const char*)some_char_buffer);
```

But if that's the case, it would be much better to instead change address to be a `char*` everywhere:

```
char* address;
```

Depending on your codebase that may be a larger change. Do you know why it was an `unsigned long long` rather than a pointer in the first place?

---

**Alternatively, if you want the bytes  of  the content of `address` to be treated as a string**: (rather than the content that `address` might point to), do:

```
strcmp ((char*)&address, (const char*)some_char_buffer); // note the &
```

Note that you'd need the last byte in the long to be `'\0'` in this case. If this is what you want to do, I'd recommend using `strncmp()` limited to the size of the long long instead:

```
strncmp((char*)&address, (const char*)some_char_buffer, 
        sizeof(unsigned long long));
```

Comment: `NULL` (`(void *)0`) is a null pointer, ASCII NUL (`'\0'`) is what comes at the end of a C string. They're not interchangeable, even if they have the same value.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should probably be using `uintptr_t` for `address`. (I do not think the standard gives a guarantee that `unsigned long long` has enough bits to hold a pointer, even if it does often in practice.)

```
uintptr_t address = ...;
strcmp((const char *)address, some_char_buffer);
```

either that or, if you can live with the ugliness,

```
unsigned long long address = ...;
strcmp((const char *)(uintptr_t)address, some_char_buffer);
```

Comment: There is no practical benefit to casting through `uintptr_t` in your second option.  If the value in `address` was already truncated, it is too late.

Comment: Well the benefit is to shut up gcc in the second option, for example if you (for whatever reason) are assigning the result of a `strtoull` to the `address` variable. Indeed the first one (`uintptr_t address = strtoul...`) would be preferred since one cast can be replaced by an implicit conversion.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
strcmp((char*)&address, (const char*)some_char_buffer);
```